# jQuery post only sending GET data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

```
var link = 'http://www.somsite.com/sendmoney.php?confirm=1&code=10';
var amount = 10;
var myID = 1;
var data_final = {money:amount, ID:myID, tag:null};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        'url' : link,
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : data_final,
        'headers': {
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Referer':'http://www.somesite.com/sendmoney.php',
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
            'User-Agent':navigator.userAgent
        }
    });
});
```

I am sending the following request using jQuery which is a post request, the weird thing is that the request is only sending the GET query and not the POST query

It is only sending `confirm=1` and `code=10` and not the rest of the data.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: How are you testing whether the post data isn't coming through?

Comment: check your devtools for the content headers and data and post here

Comment: @m.t.bennett I'm using an HTTP request monitor, specifically charles, it shows me that the only data being sent is what's in the link

Comment: try sending with `data-type: 'json',` in there as well (to troubleshoot and just reply whether it fails or succeeds)

Comment: anytime :) I'm gonna add as the answer so you can accept and others can benefit as well

Comment: Try removing the `Content-Type` header (jQuery should handle that for you automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Set your AJAX to send using JSON like so:

```
...
    $.ajax({
        'url' : link,
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : data_final,
        'data-type' : 'json',
...
```